# Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI - cant seem to be able to figure out

Tags: solidity, remix, error

I looked thru the past threads for this error but still couldnt figure out how i can resolve this. One method i saw was to generate an ABI and manually insert it but i cant seem to figure out how this can be done even after copying the ABI and parsing it through abi.hashex(it doesnt give me the 00000 numbers).

[image]

As such, can anyone help and guide me on how i can resolve this error? Appreciate your help.

The contract source code is a copy of this.
https://bscscan.com/address/0xc31a3446de3a54e306e7e46e636189dc9a5cda64#code

i used progma 0.6.12, optimized(yes, 200 runs) but still cant for the hell of it figure out why this wont work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this to generate your abi https://abi.hashex.org/#. Add constructor parameters if and paste the abi in  generated bytecode space while verifying.